# Creating a UILabel when it's a property

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, properties, uilabel

I think I'm been a little daft here but I'm wondering if you could shed some light on this.

I have a single view app with a view and a button. In my `viewControllers` button action I want to create a label on screen.

If I create a label with: `UIlabel * label = [UIlabel alloc] initwithframe...` It works fine.

However if I give my viewController a uilabel property and then try and create a label with : `self.mylabel = [UILabel alloc] initWithFrame...` When I add the label it does not appear.

I know there are other ways to achieve this and all but I was just wondering why this happens, unless I'm been a massive idiot that is!!!

Has anyone got any thoughts?

Comment: where are you creating the label? where are you adding the label? you should not access self.view, while beeing in your init method. use viewDidLoad, or loadView to add view elements.

Comment: I'm using the IBAction from my button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are adding it as a subview to the viewController's view.

`[self.view addSubview:label]`

Comment: Perfect answer.. You have to add it as subview of self.view then only it will appear..

Comment: I used [self.view addSubView:self.myLabel];

Answer (score 0):

In all probability at the time you are adding the label to your view your label is nil. If you are sure that your label is at least being allocated correctly then check explicitly how it is being retained (or not retained) in it's @property declaration.

For instance if you have declared it **weak** then you need to be initialising and using the label in scope.

Put a breakpoint on the code where you are adding the label to the view to give you a clue as to what is happening.